# openmpi, termios and stdin

Tags: stdin, file-descriptor, openmpi, termios

I've a question regarding openmpi and the standard input file descriptor (fd)
and the use of termios.
Is actually the standard fd used in ompi programs ?

There's the mpirun `-stdin` option for standard input redirection to a certain rank. I assume something is done behind the scene.

For example, the following code snippet fails at `tcgetattr` for STDIN_FILENO only with mpirun (but works in sequential).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int in = dup( STDIN_FILENO );
  struct termios org_opts, new_opts;
  res = tcgetattr( in, &org_opts);
  assert(res==0);

  MPI_Finalize( );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Open MPI, `stdin` is read by the `mpirun` process.

Then the data read is *forwarded* to one MPI task (task 0 unless explicitly requested otherwise), and that could involve the `orted` daemon(s).

Bottom line, and from the point of view of the MPI task that is *forwarded* `stdin`, file descriptor zero is a `pipe` to the local daemon (`mpirun` or `orted`), and that is why `tcgetattr()` and friends fail.

Note all other MPI tasks have file descriptor zero pointing to `/dev/null`.

IIRC, `SLURM` provides a `srun` option (e.g. direct-run) in which `stdin` is a pseudo-terminal.